# Rails .where json model attribute is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a model Activity which has a column `content_basic` with `type :json`. I want to find all activities where `content_basic` doesn't include `"session_overview_path"`.

For example I've got `Activity.find(1)` without `session_overview_path`:

```
=>
 id: 1,
 cms_activity_id: 1,
 is_separate_activity: false,
 content_basic: {"content_type"=>"Audio", "title"=>"Audio title test", "is_separate_activity"=>true, "duration"=>2},
```

and `Activity.find(2)` with `session_overview_path` inside `content_basic`:

```
=>
 id: 2,
 cms_activity_id: 1234,
 is_separate_activity: false,
 content_basic: {"content_type"=>"Audio", "session_overview_path"=>"/29388/test.png", "title"=>"Audio title test", "is_separate_activity"=>true, "duration"=>2},
```

How to find those Activities without `session_overview_path`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following

```
where("(content_basic->'session_overview_path') IS NULL ")
```